# clear last exception error from PHPMailer for next loop

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, phpmailer

lets say i have this:

```
$emails = array('some1@email.com', 'some2@email', 'some3@email.com', 'some4@email.com');
foreach ($emails as $email) {
    try {
        $mail->addAddress($email);
        $mail->send();
        $mail->clearAddresses();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        if (strpos($e->errorMessage(), $email) > 0) {
            // so here i can see if i have error like: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: some2@email
            echo $e->errorMessage();
            echo "<br>";
            echo $email;
        }
        else {
            // so i would see if there is another error, like smtp login failed etc
// here unfortunately on third loop it gives me error from second loop that some2@email is nto valid even when i sent some3@email.com
            die($e->errorMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

so the exception in next loop is remembered and displayed, the output above is:

```
SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: some2@email: L6gvk4HSs0vIlL6gvkzbQ0 invalid destination domain <some2@email>
some3@email.com
```

so my question is, how do i clear the error after i process it so i can start fresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the exception at the second address, the line with `$mail->clearAddresses()` is never reached.

So your third mail wil be sent to both `some2@email` and `some3@email.com`, throwing the exception again.

```
try {
    $mail->addAddress($email);
    $mail->send(); // try block stops here on exception
    $mail->clearAddresses(); // addresses are not cleared
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // ...
}
```

You can call `$mail->clearAddresses()` outside of the `try, catch` statement.

```
try {
    $mail->addAddress($email);
    $mail->send();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // ...
}
$mail->clearAddresses();
```

You can also call `$mail->clearAddresses()` before you call `$mail->addAddress($email)`. That way you will always be sure the addresses are cleared before you add one.

```
try {
    $mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->addAddress($email);
    $mail->send();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // ...
}
```